# Angular animate with selectbox filters

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to animate the results that my filter shows in my small angular app... The point, however, is that it just renders new List items instead of hiding/showing all the items etc.

How can I get my results to fadeout/in when the user is filtering?

I've created a pen for my current code: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mPxEGE

I've tried adding `ng-animate="{enter: 'animate-enter', leave: 'animate-leave'}"` to my list item, to no avail. It just removes the LI entirely when not used in the filter.
P.s I've noticed my "Male" filter isnt working properly :')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the css for `animate-enter` and `animate-leave`

- For Enter: animate-enter & animate-enter-active
- For Leave: animate-leave & animate-leave-active

like specified [here](http://www.nganimate.org/angularjs/tutorial/how-to-make-animations-with-angularjs)

So add :

```
.animate-enter {
    -webkit-transition: 1s linear all; /* Chrome */
    transition: 1s linear all;
    opacity: 0;
}

.animate-enter.animate-enter-active {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Here is an [updated codepen](http://codepen.io/lulylulu/pen/BKrzgd?editors=1111). My animations are not very good ^^

PS. you also don't need to inject `ngAnimate` into the controller.

Comment: Your code set me on the right track. However it still didn't work. Using angular 1.1.5 instead of 1.5.0 did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I've add a class on your `<li>` element and an appropriate css and it works.

**HTML**

```
<li class="item" ng-repeat="item in items | filter:search:strict">
        {{item.name}}
</li>
```

**CSS**

```
.item.ng-move,
.item.ng-enter,
.item.ng-leave {
  -webkit-transition:all linear 0.5s;
  transition:all linear 0.5s;
}

.item.ng-leave.ng-leave-active,
.item.ng-move,
.item.ng-enter {
  opacity:0;
}

.item.ng-leave,
.item.ng-move.ng-move-active,
.item.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
  opacity:1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Animations via angular can only be implemented in 2 ways. Via the $animate provider or through CSS.

```
/*


We're using CSS transitions for when
  the enter and move events are triggered
  for the element that has the .repeated-item
  class
*/
.repeated-item.ng-enter, .repeated-item.ng-move {
  -webkit-transition:0.5s linear all;
  -moz-transition:0.5s linear all;
  -o-transition:0.5s linear all;
  transition:0.5s linear all;
  opacity:0;
}

/*
 The ng-enter-active and ng-move-active
 are where the transition destination properties
 are set so that the animation knows what to
 animate.
*/
.repeated-item.ng-enter.ng-enter-active,
.repeated-item.ng-move.ng-move-active {
  opacity:1;
}
```

http://codepen.io/TheLarkInn/pen/qZoaWE

Here is a codepen implementing animations for your repeated list. This example comes directly from the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/animations).